# Is figcaption allowed to be a child of an <a> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, anchor, w3c-validation

I thought that in HTML5 you could have block elements as children of `<a>` elements, as understood from the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a

> Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only
>   containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous
>   versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now
>   transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to
>   also contain flow content (essentially, what was in previous versions
>   referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance
>   of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow
>   content.

But now when I checked my page with an HTML validator I found this error message:

> Error: Element “figcaption” not allowed as child of element “a” in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

The code goes as follows:

```html
<figure class="post">
  <a href="#" title="foo">
    <figcaption class="articuloInfo ">
      <h3>FOO</h3>
      <p class="fecha">4/04/2014</p>
      <div class="descripcion">
      </div>
    </figcaption>
    <div class="imagen">
      <img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo">
    </div>
  </a>
</figure>
```

Can someone explain me where the error is and why?

Comment: `<figcaption>`s are not [flow content](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#flow-content).

Comment: @Alohci what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ because it’s outdated ([it’s](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-html-markup-20130528/) a Working Group Note from 2013). The HTML5 specification is: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/

For the [`figcaption` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element), the spec lists "Contexts in which this element can be used", wich are:

> As the first or last child of a [`figure`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) element.

It says *child* (not *descendant*), so it can’t have an `a` element as parent.

You could place the `a` element around the `figure` element instead (which is possible because of the part you quoted: `a` can contain flow content now):

```html
<a href="#" title="foo">
  <figure class="post">
    <!-- … -->
  </figure>
</a>
```

Comment: In fact, HTML5.0 specification snapshot is also outdated. The current W3C HTML version, HTML5.1 (which is planned to become Rec. this autumn), allows `figcaption` [anywhere in the `figure`](https://github.com/w3c/html/pull/181). However, the current WHATWG Living Standard edition still requires that `figcaption` must be only the first or the last child (not 'descendant') of the `figure`, like W3C HTML5.0.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn: Good info about the change in HTML 5.1, thanks! (But I don’t consider HTML5 to be outdated, as it’s W3C’s most current Recommendation for HTML, as HTML 5.1 is still a Working Draft.)

Comment: I also used to think that published snapshots of W3C specs are actual standards and Working Drafts are experimental things for the future. But I had to change my mind after [this topic](https://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4672800.htm#msg4679983). It appears that even not Working Drafts, but the most recent Editor's Drafts are the spec versions that implementors are interested in.

Comment: It seems that the `figcaption` can have an `a` element as a child, though. Helpful to link the caption itself.

Answer (score 2):

A figurecaption can have only figure element as its parent:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption

So a figure caption cannot be a direct child of an anchor  tag.